# Which parameters are better to be stored in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I'm developing a social app using Vue.js and Vuex store to keep app's relevant variables around.

Now I'm wondering if there are any best practices as to which parameters are better to be kept in browsers's localStorage?

Currently I keep `token` in localStorage, but wondering whether I should also keep `username` and other pertinent user data in localStorage, in order to preserve them from being perished on page refresh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no correct answer here; just some thoughts:

Unless you have a good reason to, I wouldn't store the username in local storage. What advantage would you have by dong so? If the user logged in to their account from a different browser and changed their username, that would invalidate the username stored in local storage on other browsers. Most users expect that reloading the page should completely refresh all the data. People will think your site is broken if they reload the page and the username didn't update. The less stuff you store in local storage, the less you need to worry about the data becoming stale.

At a minimum, you should definitely store authentication token in local storage. From that, you can make requests to the server on page load to obtain all other data including the user itself.

Comment: One advantage of keeping `username` in localStorage is to preserve it against page refresh. How can I do that if I keep username in the Vuex store? (I'm using JWT token)

Comment: But why are you worrying about just the username? *All* data is lost on page refresh. You need to make a request to the server on page load to fetch the data again, unless you store it in local storage, but then you need to deal with the data becoming stale. It's just more work for you, you're gonna have to make a request to the server to get this info in the first place anyway, so just use that method.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you need to store anything in local storage at all. If you have some authentication setup, you could store just your token in a session cookie and retrieve all needed data from the server.

Trying to keep the saved data on the client to a minimum is a good idea. Just keep the token in cookie, retrieve username (and so on) from the server when first loading the page. The retrieved data can be stored in some javascript vars. These values get only cleared on a page reload and then you have to retrieve them once from the server.

Reloads should not occur often or not at all, when you have a single page app.

Comment: I don't use cookes. I use JWT token.

Comment: I think you are mixing up some concepts. A JWT token is in abstract a piece of information that is signed and encoded. In the end it is just a string. This information can be stored any place you like, e.g. in a cookie or in local storage.